# Angular 2 *ngIf not working at first loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-ng-if

I am working on Angular 2 rc1 version
I have an loading issue with *ngIf

My code as below

```
export class PlansComponent implements OnInit{
  plan_id: string = 'free';
}
```

Component

```
<button class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="plan_id == 'free'">Free</button>
```

This page is loaded by using navigate method of router object in another page

```
this.router.navigate(['/plans']);
```

The button with *ngIf will be not shown at the first time. After I refresh/reload page the button will work correctly.

I don know the reason why the first time is not working

Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way this could happens is that you DOM has loaded before the view-model(instance of your class) and since it has no model field to evaluate `ngIf` becomes false. Try initializing your variable inside the onInit function like this.

```
export class PlansComponent implements OnInit{
 plan_id: string;

 ngOnInit(){
    plan_id = "free";
 }
}
```

Because according to the developer guide **ngOnInit** lifecycle hook does the following

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the
>   data-bound input properties.